# Nontrivial Twists of a Vector Bundle

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, vector-bundles, galois-cohomology

Let $k$ be a number field, and let $X$ be a projective $k$-variety. Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a vector bundle on $X$ that is defined over $k$. A vector bundle $\mathcal{V}'$ on $X$ that is defined over $k$ is said to be a twist of $\mathcal{V}$ if there is some finite extension $\ell/k$ such that we have an isomorphism $\mathcal{V}_\ell \simeq \mathcal{V}'_\ell$ of bundles upon basechanging to $\ell$.

Question: Is it true that all twists of $\mathcal{V}$ are in fact isomorphic to $\mathcal{V}$ over $k$?

What I know: Twists are parameterized by the Galois cohomology group $H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k),\operatorname{Aut}(\cal{V}_{\overline{k}}))$, so all we need to do is determine whether this cohomology group is equal to $0$. It's a consequence of Hilbert Theorem 90 that $H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k),\operatorname{GL}_n(\overline{k})) = 0$, which might be useful.

Comment: And you really need this full statement? I see how to prove the answer in the affirmative if you assume that $X$ is integral and either you're dealing with line bundles or one of your vector bundles is trivial. In the complete general case this, at first glance, seems kind of tough. You're essentially asking about the Galois cohomology of the algebraic group $R\mapsto \Aut(\mathcal{V}_R)$. Are there large constraints on what this algebraic group can be?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I'm happy to assume $X$ is integral, and I think I know how to handle the cases where $\cal{V}$ is a line bundle or is trivial. I'm interested primarily in the case where $\cal{V}$ splits completely as a direct sum of line bundles, but I'm not sure whether that constrains $\operatorname{Aut}(V)$ sufficiently. Does your argument for the line bundle case generalize to the case of the direct sum of line bundles?

Comment: No, not a priori. Again, what we're really asking is this: if $V$ is a totally decomposable vector bundle on some projective $k$-variety $X$ then does the algebraic $k$-group $R\mapsto \mathrm{Aut}(V_R)$ have any non-trivial torsors? I mean, is this group connected? Why can't it be $\mathrm{PGL}_n$? Do you know any structural results about what group this can be?

Comment: Just to point out, I think that the group $G_V(R):=\mathrm{Aut}(V_R)$ contains a central copy of $\mathbb{G}_m$, so it can't be $\mathrm{PGL}_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\GL}{\mathrm{GL}}$$\newcommand{\ov}[1]{\overline{#1}}$$\newcommand{\h}{\mathcal{O}}$$\newcommand{\Aut}{\mathrm{Aut}}$$\newcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}$$\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}$$\newcommand{\A}{\mathbb{A}}$
Thanks to a very helpful conversation with my friend P. Achinger here is a solution assuming that $X$ is geometrically integral (he has a proof even when $X$ is just proper and $k$ is infinite, but below is a simplified version in the case when geometrically integral case when $k$ is infinite).

Assume that $k$ is infinite.

Step 1: The assertion is true for line bundles. Indeed, if $L_{\ov{k}}\cong L'_{\ov{k}}$ then $(L\otimes L^{-1})_{\ov{k}}\cong (\h_X)_{\ov{k}}$. But, this then defines a a class of $H^1(\Gal(\ov{k}/k),\Aut(\h_{X_{\ov{k}}}))=H^1(\Gal(\ov{k}/k),\ov{k}^\times)=0$. It follows that $L\cong L'$.

Step 2: Let $V$ and $V'$ be vector bundles on $X$ such that $V_{\ov{k}}\cong V'_{\ov{k}}$. Note then that $\det(V)_{\ov{k}}\cong \det(V')_{\ov{k}}$ so that, by Step 1, we have that $\det(V)\cong \det(V')$. Let us now consider the functor $R\mapsto \Hom(V_R,V'_R)$. Note that by flat base change we have that this functor coincides with $R\mapsto \Hom(V,V')\otimes_k R$ and thus coincides with $\A^n_k$ where $n:=\dim \Hom(V,V')$ (which is finite-dimensional since $X$ is proper). Let $U\subseteq \A^n_k$ be defined as the functor 
$$U(R)=\{f\in\Hom(V_R,V'_R):f\text{ isomorphism}\}$$

We claim that this is an open subscheme of $\A^n_k$. Indeed, note that we have a functorial map

$$\begin{aligned}\A^n_k =&\Hom(V,V')\to\Hom(\det(V),\det(V))=\A^1_k\\ &:\varphi\mapsto\det(\varphi)\end{aligned}$$

(Where we've used the fact that $X$ is geometrically integral to identify this last term with $\A^1_k$). It's clear then that $U$ is the open subscheme of $\A^n_k$ obtained as the preimage of

$$\mathbb{G}_m\subseteq \A^1_k=\Hom(\det(V),\det(V))$$

Now by assumption we have that $U(\ov{k})\ne \varnothing$ so that $U$ is non-empty. This implies, since $k$ is infinite, that $U(k)\ne \varnothing$ (e.g see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264197/rational-points-on-open-subsets-of-affine-space)). Thus, $V\cong V'$.

**EDIT:** Here's a proof that works when $k$ is finite, and thus all cases are covered.

Let us denote by $G_V$ the group scheme over $k$ given by $R\mapsto \Aut(V_R)$. Note that, as above, we have that $G_V$ is an open subscheme of the functor $R\mapsto \mathrm{End}(V_R)$ which is identified with $\A^n_k$ where $n:=\dim\mathrm{End}(V)$. In particular, since $\A^n_k$ is irreducible we deduce that $G_V$ is connected.

Note then that since the twists of $V$ are classified by $H^1_\mathrm{et}(\mathrm{Spec}(k),G_V)$ it suffices to prove that this latter cohomology group is zero. Since $G_V$ is connected this follows from [Lang's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lang%27s_theorem).

*Remark:* It's still a little miraculous that even though the group $G_V:R\mapsto \mathrm{Aut}(V_R)$ is mysterious (at least to me) we can prove that $H^1_\mathrm{et}(\mathrm{Spec}(k),G_V)=0$. Does anyone have anything substantive to say about the structure of the group $G_V$? Is it affine? Is it reductive (note that it can't be semisimple because we have a central embedding of $\mathbb{G}_m$ into $G_V$)? If so, is it split? For example, what made the line bundle case so simple is that for any line bundle $L$ we have that $G_L\cong\mathbb{G}_m$. Unless I made a mistake, it seems like that it needn't be reductive in general since some examples on $\mathbb{P}^1$ lead me to believe that you can get things like parabolic groups in $\GL_n$.

**EDIT:** Just to point out, the group $G_V$ is evidently affine. Namely, by the discussion above we see that $\Aut(G)$ is just $D(\det)$ or, more precisely, the pullback of $\mathbb{G}_m$ along the map $\mathrm{End}(V)\to\mathrm{End}(\det(V))$ which, since this map is between affine schemes and $\mathbb{G}_m$ is affine, is affine.